# Optimize query with many AND statements in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle

is it possible to optimize this sql query in order to have better execution time in case of big sized tables

```
SELECT X.id,X.id2
FROM Table X, Table Y, Table Z, Table W
WHERE  Y.id = 1 
        AND Y.dt = Z.dty 
        AND Z.el = 2 
        AND Z.id = W.idz 
        AND W.idx = X.id
```

Comment: The query itself looks fine.  Are you asking about a specific problem you're having?  If so, it would help to post lots of details, such as the time the query takes to run, the number of rows returned, the size of the tables (in rows or bytes), if there are indexes, how well do the predicates filter the data (if one of the conditions retrieves only 0.01% of the rows then an index would be useful), and the explain plan from `explain plan for ...` and `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);`

Answer (score 1):

Use proper standard explicit *JOIN* Syntax instead of commas:

```
SELECT X.id, X.id2 
FROM Table X INNER JOIN
     Table W 
     ON W.idx = X.id INNER JOIN
     Table Z
     ON Z.id = W.idz INNER JOIN
     Table Y
     ON Y.dt = Z.dty
WHERE Y.id = 1 AND Z.el = 2;
```

Just make sure you will have indexes on `X(ID), W(idx), Z(id,dty,el), Y(dt,id)`

Comment: While I totally agree with that recommendation, it will not have any impact on the performance